# How to get Application's Version programmatically

Tags: java, eclim

I've set Eclim's :ProjectSettings (org.eclim.project.version) and I'm now wondering how to print it out in my main class.

`System.out.format("Version: %s", org.eclim.project.version);` didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I also don't know much about it but this comes from what I have searched:

Firstly the "org.eclim.project.version" is used to set the project properties either in an xml file or a properties file.
Then you can access it through an annotation @Version

You ca refer to :
http://eclim.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=eclim/eclim;a=commitdiff;h=b8c2b7f90c4eb459c7913eb36948a7a2feae95b2